# motorola mc3190 hanging processes

Tags: motorola, pocketpc

I am very new with motorola mc3190 and c#. I can't deploy my application anymore cause the .exe file is in use by another process. I found that process but I can't kill it. How can I kill a process hanging on my mc3190?

Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disconnecting then reconnecting from your base if you are using a base with USB tether. If that doesn't work, then try doing a warm boot on the device (usually by holding down the power button for five seconds on this series of devices).

Answer (score 2):

To stop a process from being hung make sure you are disposing of all of your objects on exiting.. i just noticed that i would have background processors running on similar devices if i hadn't disposed of the scanner object or etc...